# coming to the shops or going to the shops?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

Which of the following sentences are correct?

> 1. Do you mind COMING to the shops with me?
> 2. Do you mind GOING to the shops with me?

Comment: Either one is fine. You might want to check out [ell.se].

Answer (score 4):

They're both correct, and the difference between the two is subtle.

To my mind, as a native speaker of British English, if I ask

> Do you mind **coming** to the shops with me?

...it would imply that I will go to the shops, regardless of whether you accompany me or not. In a sense, I would be 'leading' our expedition, and we would be visiting these emporia chiefly for my own purposes. However, asking

> Do you mind **going** to the shops with me?

...connotes that my travelling to the shops is contingent on your coming with me, or at the very least, I have yet to make up mind.

As I said, though, this really is a point of nuance in meaning, and as such it is likely to differ between regions, dialects and quite probably individuals.

Comment: Wow! The difference, as you mentioned, seems very subtle but deeply interesting to me. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, thank you @Frank, I'll keep on fighting the good fight ;)

Answer (score 3):

Either would be fine, but to my ears the difference would be in tense.

> Do you mind **coming** to the shops with me?

I would take this to mean now, or imminently.

> Do you mind **going** to the shops with me?

I would take to mean, tomorrow, next week, next month, etc.

However, for each you’d have to take it in the context of the overall conversation.

Comment: Use the '>' character at the start of a line for blockquotes instead of the backticks used for 'code'.